# Firebase referencing old database

Tags: android, firebase

I set up a Firebase realtime database in an Android app, but I chose the wrong location, so I deleted the Firebase project. I then made a new project and did the exact same steps (yes, I did swap out the google-services.json file). However, when I try to access the database, through FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() for example, it still refers to the old project (which I can tell by the project id).
Also, when I do FirebaseApp.getApps(), it only contains the app with the "old" project id. After this didn't work, I did it all over again on a new branch, and it somehow still refers to the old project. I can see the correct project id in the google-services.json file, why is it not using it?

Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Relevant module gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try out this simple solution..

1. remove the old google-services.json from your project.
2. uninstall previous version of your app in device/emulator.
3. place new google-services.json
4. clean and rebuilt before launching it to device.
5. hit run.